# Post video url link which is playable on wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API, I would like to post (on the wall) an url link that points to a mp4 file. However Facebook doesn't show the file in a video player instead it's just a link which opens in a new browser window.

Is it possible to post an mp4 url link which Facebook will display using the Facebook video player, allowing the user to watch it directly on the user wall?

Comment: Example video http://www.sample-videos.com/video/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4

Comment: That is a http link. Needs to be https

Comment: So for instance if you just post this link manually on your wall it will only display as a link.

Comment: Yea. Web browsers don't allow http content on a https site

Comment: Ahhh, I see, so if this would be located on a https server the video would be treated like a video on the wall?

Comment: Didn't work either :(